# Updated Google App Engine and now I have an error TypeError: 'NoneType' object is unsubscriptable

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I updated the GoogleAppEngineLauncher last night and now I'm getting this error

```
<type 'exceptions.TypeError'>   Python 2.6.1: /usr/bin/python
Tue Nov 8 09:25:13 2011
A problem occurred in a Python script. Here is the sequence of function calls leading up to the error, in the order they occurred.

 /Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py in _HandleRequest(self=<google.appengine.tools.dev_appserver.DevAppServerRequestHandler instance at 0x114cef368>)
<type 'exceptions.TypeError'>: 'NoneType' object is unsubscriptable 
      args = ("'NoneType' object is unsubscriptable",) 
      message = "'NoneType' object is unsubscriptable"
```

Any ideas what is going on?

Comment: I ended up just restoring my GoogleAppEngineLauncher from a time machine backup, and that fixed my problem for now, but I'm not sure why the update caused a problem. I'm assuming it is because the launcher now supports python 2.7?

Comment: Getting the error where? When doing what? Where is the stacktrace?

Comment: Can you add both the stacktrace and the line of code (with context if necessary) that generated the exception?

Comment: I'm sorry, like I mentioned, I reverted my GoogleAppEngineLauncher from a backup, so I can't tell you the stacktrace. A few days ago I updated to 2.7 with no problems, so I'm all set. Sorry I couldn't be of more help.

Answer (score 0):

GAE uses Python 2.7.x if specified in the app.yaml, 2.5.x else. 
When launching with 2.6.x it gives unpredictable errors.